# Assigning and updating the image part of a Canvas widget in tkinter (Error)

Tags: python, image, canvas, python-3.x, tkinter

Firstly, I am aware that there are similar solutions out there, and I have looked at all of them. None of them have worked- this is not a duplicate. My program is a hangman program that updates the image depending on how many wrong guesses the player has given. Here is my code. Feel free to edit and cut out irrelevant code. I have not because I don't understand the error. The code:

```
import random,time,sys
from tkinter import *

sys.path.append('C:/Users/Thornton/Desktop/Python Stuff/PyHang/images/') #defining the full path

class App:

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        global e1,game

        Label(frame,text='Guess').grid(row=2)
        e1=Entry(frame)
        e1.grid(row=2,column=1)

        slider=Scrollbar(frame)
        slider.grid(row=1,column=2)
        self.game=Listbox(frame,height=3,yscrollcommand=slider.set)
        self.game.grid(row=1,column=1)
        slider.config(command=self.game.yview)

        self.status=Canvas(frame,width=220,height=125) #creating the canvas
        self.status.grid(row=0,column=1)

        Button(frame,text='OK',command=self.guess).grid(row=2,column=2)
        root.bind('<Return>',self.guess)
        Button(frame,text="New\nGame",command=self.new_game).grid(row=1,column=0)
        root.bind('<Home>',self.new_game)

        self.new_game()

    def guess(self,event=None):
        frame=Frame()
        frame.pack()
        global losses

        letter=e1.get().strip()
        if len(letter)!=1 or letter.isdigit() or letter in self.used:
            pass
        else:
            self.used.append(letter)
            if letter in self.secret:
                self.game.insert(END,"\n",'Correct!')
                positions=[i for i,item in enumerate(self.secret) if item==letter]
                for place in positions:
                    self.display[place]=letter
            else:
                self.game.insert(END,"\n",'Incorrect.')
                self.losses+=1
                self.status.image=PhotoImage(str(losses) + '.gif') #updating image
            self.game.insert(END,''.join(self.display),'Used: ' + ''.join(self.used))
            if self.losses==6:
                self.game.insert(END,'You Lose.',"(" + ''.join(self.secret) + ")")
            elif self.display==self.secret:
                self.game.insert(END,'You Win!')
            self.game.yview(END)
        e1.delete(0,END)

    def new_game(self,event=None):
        frame=Frame()
        frame.pack()
        global game,losses,used,secret,display

        self.secret=list(random.choice(open('dictionary.txt').readlines()))
        del self.secret[-1]

        self.losses=0
        self.used=[]
        self.display=['*' for letter in self.secret]

        self.status.image=PhotoImage(file='0.gif') #resetting image
        self.status.create_image(image=self.status.image)

        e1.delete(0,END)
        self.game.delete(0,END)
        self.game.insert(END,''.join(self.display))

root = Tk()
root.title('PyHang 2.0')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
File "C:\Users\Thornton\Desktop\Python Stuff\PyHang\pyhang2.0.py", line 72, in new_game
  self.status.image=PhotoImage(file='0.gif')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3287, in __init__
  Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3243, in __init__
  self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "0.gif": no such file or directory
```

The images are in the folder `images`, range from `0` to `6.gif` and correspond to the variable `losses`. All the files exist and as you can see I have defined the full path. Please be patient as I am new to tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may have misunderstood `sys.path` as it is for locating imported Python modules. It doesn't help find the GIF in `PhotoImage(file='0.gif')`. The error is stating the the image was not found, so you just need to use the right relative path from where you run the script (or use the absolute path to the image).

To verify this, change this:

```
    self.status.image=PhotoImage(file='0.gif') #resetting image
```

to this:

```
    self.status.image=PhotoImage(file='images/0.gif') #resetting image
```

Note: this assumes the script and the images directory are both in the same directory and you are running the script from within that directory.

Comment: Now I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range` once making the suggested modifications and running the code. Run the program fo3 the full error code.

Comment: That is correct, I can verify the same error. However, that is a different issue, this is the answer to this question. You can always ask a different question.

Comment: looking around I managed to solve it. Thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out. You just needed to tell the canvas where you wanted to position the image. Happy coding!